# Save parameters when application is closed

Tags: c, windows-runtime, windows-phone

How do I save parameters before closing my Windows Phone Runtime app and use these parameters when I activate my app? I have a String and an int that I need to save.

Comment: This is really well documented ..., like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361 have you tried an option that doesn't work? You'll need to periodically save the parameters.

Comment: Remove WP RT from your question title and put this information clearly into your question itself please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LocalSettings for that.

Use below code to save values in to the settings

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "test";
```

to retrieve settings use below code

```
var value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] as string;
```

More details available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361)

Comment: It worked, thanks @NullPointer, I just need to figure how do this for lists